# Symfony 4 : Default value for parameters with a class type can only be

Tags: php, symfony4

I am currently working on an application in symfony 4. I encounter a problem for deploy in prod. when I get to the navigator I get this error :

> Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type can only be NULL in /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php on line 40.

```
public function __construct(string $file, iterable $resourceCheckers = array())
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->resourceCheckers = $resourceCheckers;
}
```

I specify that the site works perfectly with the dev server (php bin /console server:start)

The problem must come from the environment. in the .env file, when I set APP_ENV=dev , in the browser there is only a blank page with a status 500 (no message in the logs)

I can not find any documentation on the internet and I am starting to lack ideas. If someone has a solution I am interested.

Thank you.

Comment: What is _on line 40_? And what are PHP versions of prod and dev?

Comment: Have you tried clearing and warming the production cache?

Comment: Graeme Chapman, yes I already cleaned the cache but cala did not make any changes.

Comment: AbraCadaver line 40 corresponds to its:   public function __construct(string $file, iterable $resourceCheckers = array())
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->resourceCheckers = $resourceCheckers;
    }

Answer (score 2):

*Solution by OP.*

The problem was that the PHP version was PHP 7.0 and not 7.1. Though in my shell the `php -v` command was fine with 7.1, I noticed the wrong version used by `phpinfo ();`

Comment: thanks, having the same issue, but how to force php using the correct version?

Comment: @emfi you need to ask OP (lucas monroe): I don't use PHP.