# Symfony 4 - Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony4

I have a similar problem than here : [Symfony 4 : Default value for parameters with a class type can only be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348650/symfony-4-default-value-for-parameters-with-a-class-type-can-only-be]) but when I launch composer commands... :

```
executing script security-checker security:check [KO]
 [KO]
Script security-checker security:check returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 83
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
When I launched for example : php7 composer.phar update, because I had the same problem for others commands...
```

I don't understand because I use the 7.1.8 PHP version... I installed the whole project with my PHP 7.1.8... :/

Code affected :

```
/**
     * @param string $name    The name of the application
     * @param string $version The version of the application
     */
    public function __construct(string $name = 'UNKNOWN', string $version = 'UNKNOWN') // Line affected HERE (line 83)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->version = $version; 
        $this->terminal = new Terminal();
        $this->defaultCommand = 'list';
    }
```

An idea for me ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Could you post the affected code?

Comment: It's okay. The affected line is the first (of the function). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're running on PHP 7? Composer maybe uses a different PHP version than your webserver. What do you get when you run `php -v` on the command line?

Comment: I have an alias php7. When I run my alias "php7 -v", I get this : PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2017 11:34:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: ..and when you just run `php -v` and not your PHP 7 alias?

Comment: ha, it changed too to 7.1.8... But normally, I want PHP 5.6 with the php command. I changed this for moment in Mamp to be sure to have the 7.1.8 version for CLI, too.

Comment: Well I suspect that composer is using PHP 5.6 then

Comment: I have my specific PHP CLI in PhpStorm. It's okay. On my composer.json, I have this line : "php": "^7.1.3". Composer doens't use this information to use the appropriate PHP ?

Comment: AFAIK this has only an impact on the dependency versions. Composer usually uses the PHP version defined in your PATH

Comment: OK... I don't understand at all why. it doens't work I tried with the whole path to PHP 7.1.8 and it continues to not work... But Symfony 4 is stable, alright ? I guess I'll install Symfony 3, what a pity. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's OK to do that... I replaced this line in composer.json :

```
 "security-checker security:check": "script"
```

by :

```
 "security:check": "symfony-cmd"
```

I guess and hope the command is the same. I don't understand why. I follow the official documentation of Symfony 4 and I have the correct PHP version. :/

I don't know at all... TT__TT